# difference reading system properties with RuntimeMXBean instance and System.getProperties

Tags: java

what is the difference between reading system properties in this different ways

```
RuntimeMXBean RuntimemxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
Object value =  RuntimemxBean.getSystemProperties();
System.out.println(value);
```

*AND*

```
Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
systemProperties.list(System.out);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in Sun JVM, the result should be the same as `RuntimeMXBean.getSystemProperties()` calls `System.getProperties()` internally.

```
public Map<String, String> getSystemProperties() {
    Properties localProperties = System.getProperties();
    HashMap localHashMap = new HashMap();

    Set localSet = localProperties.stringPropertyNames();
    for (String str1 : localSet) {
      String str2 = localProperties.getProperty(str1);
      localHashMap.put(str1, str2);
    }

    return localHashMap;
}
```

The difference is you can use `RuntimeMXBean` from a remote JVM ([see 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/package-summary.html#examples)) to obtain its system properties.

Comment: very helpful, as far I know JMX API is the right way to monitoring local and remote JVM's